# How to reliably list ephemeral storage of an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How can I list the actual block-device name(s) of ephemeral storage available in my EC2 instance?

After some trials and errors, it *appears* that such devices are connected as `/dev/xvdn` (and `/dev/xvdm` if there are two) -- is there some way to reliably list them from inside the instance?

`fdisk -l` lists all devices -- without anything obviously distinctive about `/dev/xvdn`. Same goes for output of `lsblk`. (We aren't using Amazon's own AMI-instances, so there is no `-p` flag for `lsblk`...)

Request for `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0` returns `sdj`, but there is no `/dev/sdj`, so that seems useless... Is there anything better?

The minor device-number seems to be 208 -- can one rely on that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the setup to check if this this specific to Amazon Linux AMIs, but on my setup here, `/dev/sdX` is symlinked to the corresponding `/dev/xvdX` device.

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0 --> sdb`

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-61-112 ~]$ ls -lrt /dev/sd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun 24 01:06 /dev/sdb -> xvdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun 24 01:07 /dev/sda -> xvda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Jun 24 01:07 /dev/sda1 -> xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun 24 02:09 /dev/sdf -> xvdf
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-61-112 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0   30G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Request for
>   http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0
>   returns sdj, but there is no /dev/sdj, so that seems useless... Is
>   there anything better?

The above is your best bet. The reason you don't see an `sdj` device is due to a discrepancy between how AWS refers to the devices they attach to your instance and how your OS names those devices. Amazon is saying that it's `sdj`, which in your case, is actually `/dev/xvdj`.

Comment: Well, there is no `/dev/xvdj` either -- on this particular instance -- there is only `/dev/xvdn`.

Comment: For nvme devices, block device mappings are completely useless.